# how to custom sort an array based on its status followed by another field?

Tags: arrays, sorting

So I have an array, I need to sort it based on status in the following order i.e. failure->warn->completed.
Normally, I use lodash for sorting but its a bit of complex order here. It also needs to sort according to run after sorting with run. Im not sure how to start on this.

```
var arr = [{"status":"failure","name":"one","run":1},
{"status":"failure","name":"two","run":2},
{"status":"warn","name":"three","run":1},
{"status":"warn","name":"four","run":2},
{"status":"completed","name":"five","run":1}]
```

Comment: just a suggestion, I'd first modify the array to include a seperate statusId field, which has corresponding integers in the order you want. i.e. failure=1,warn=2,completed=3 and so on and sort by that.

Comment: Thakk you for suggestion, solved it by doing the same.

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

1. Add a extra property for your sort key.

> ```
> var arrnew =   arr.map(function(item){
>     switch(item.status){
>     case "failure": 
>     item.statusId=1;
>     break;
>     case "warn": 
>     item.statusId=2;}
>     //...
>      return item} );
> ```

2. Sort by using that

> _.sortBy(arrnew, 'statusId');

Answer (score 0):

Sorts based on "status", and then the sub-slices by "run" 1 or 2:

```
let status_vals = [ "failure", "warn", "completed" ];

let arr = [
  {"status":"failure","name":"one","run":1},
  {"status":"failure","name":"two","run":2},
  {"status":"warn","name":"three","run":1},
  {"status":"warn","name":"four","run":2},
  {"status":"completed","name":"five","run":1}
];

function sortIt ( status_arr, sort_arr ) {

  let sorted_arr = [];
  status_arr.forEach ( d => {
    let temp = arr.filter ( obj => {
      return obj.status === d;
    } );  

    var length = temp.length;
    for ( var i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
      if ( temp [ 0 ].run > temp [ i ].run ) {
        temp.push ( temp.shift ( ) );
      }
    }

    sorted_arr = [ ...sorted_arr, ...temp ];
  } );

  return sorted_arr;
}

sortIt ( status_vals, arr );
```